# How can I add an animation or video to a peer review report without using "unprofessional" sites like imgur or youtube?

Tags: website, online-resource

I am writing a peer review and there is an animation I want to share along with it. I can't embed it in the PDF, so what other options do I have besides websites like imgur or youtube that lack professionality? I often like to refer to and post content on these sites, e.g. when doing peer review, but it feels a little unprofessional due to the ads and other recommendations.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confused. Do you also incorporate references to Discord, Facebook or Twitter in reviews? The issue with those isn't the platform, it's the quality and verifiability of any factual element in the content itself.

Comment: Vimeo seems to have a slightly more professional appearance than youtube.

Comment: @user176372 like, I'm writing a peer review for an article, and there's an animation that I want to share with them. But I can't embed it in a PDF, so I need to put it somewhere. YouTube just feels funny because when they watch It. They'll see Mr. Beast suggestions and a lot of other unprofessional stuff..

Comment: @TomSolberg: Why can't you just submit the animation as a separate file together with your review?

Comment: @TomSolberg Oh, I see. To verify: You would like to include video or image content that you made yourself in your review? Jochen should just turn his comment into an answer, then. Worst case scenario, contact the editor with whom you're corresponding to figure it out. Though also I would remark that the vast majority of possible animations and video content are unprofessional to include in this setting in math and science. I can't judge your particular field, however.

Comment: I would think the suggestion by @JochenGlueck is the best option, as it ensures there is no ex parte communication between reviewer and authors. If that's not possible, maybe you could use a data repository site. There are several that can be used in a way that [preserves anonymity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/128143/17254), and have support for in-browser viewing of images and videos.

Comment: @JochenGlueck that would be fine, except for e.g. file size limits and annoying things like "Windows can't open this media file".

Comment: Providing this infrastructure is the responsibility of the journal, not the reviewer. I'd talk to the editor who requested your review to decide on the best course of action.

Comment: There's really nothing unprofessional about putting it on youtube... Just make sure it's unlisted

Comment: You might also be interested in [IPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler [Magnet URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) are more widely supported than IPFS, with the same upsides and similar downsides.

Comment: You should indicate if you want a free site, which will probably have advertisements, or how much you are willing to pay. The precise video format may also be relevant, or at least what kind of resolution and length it is. Also do you want a site you can stream or embed it from or is it OK just to have it as a download, in which case any file sharing site would do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend [Figshare](http://figshare.com) which supports sharing scientific data in various formats (images, videos, structured data, code, etc). You have the option to share with or without creating a DOI. However, beware that in the context of blind peer-review this might allow authors to identify you.

[Zenodo](https://zenodo.org) is also a good option, but in this case associating a DOI is not optional.

Alternatively, you could just send the video to the editor to share with the authors.

Answer (score 20):

It is the responsibility of the journal to provide you with the means to effectively do your job as a reviewer. So, if you need to share an animation file, you can ask the journal for advice on how to do that.

At the same time, consider the possibility that the fact that the journal does not offer a convenient way to share animation files suggests that they do not think sharing such files is appropriate or necessary in the context of a peer review. In other words, unless they have indicated otherwise, they expect a written review, so that’s what you should probably aim to provide them with.

Comment: Also it may be worth considering that the animation file's metadata could potentially leak information about the reviewer's identity - especially if it is a self-generated file.

Answer (score 13):

I'm an EiC for a journal, have been for years. youtube and imgur domains are fine. Keep the *words* professional - nobody cares much about the website.